# JFrame ending in some time

Tags: java, swing, jframe, window

Whenever I run my code it ends in a few seconds. Why?

This is the `Main` file:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("This is running");
        GameWin Win = new GameWin();
    }
}
```

This is the `GameWin` file:

```
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class GameWin implements ActionListener{

JFrame frame = new JFrame();
JButton myButton = new JButton("New Window");

public void GameWin(){

    myButton.setBounds(100,160,200,40);
    myButton.setFocusable(false);
    myButton.addActionListener(this);

    frame.add(myButton);

    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setSize(420,420);
    frame.setLayout(null);
    frame.setVisible(true);

}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

    if(e.getSource()==myButton) {
        frame.dispose();
    }
}
}
```

When I try to run this code it shows running and then the code ends with exit code 1 which is good, but it just ends without showing the window. Is there something wrong with my JRE or JDK?

Comment: Refer - https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/codeconventions-namingconventions.html

Comment: Here,
You don't need this "void" method "public void GameWin()", rather need a constructor "public GameWin()"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Constructors do not have return type. `public void GameWin()` is not a constructor, thus the default constructor is called that does nothing interesting here. It should be declared `public GameWin()`.
2. You **must** call any Swing-related function in the Swing-main-thread for consistency. Thus call the construction of the `GameWin` object through `SwingUtilities` class. Even if it seems to work without such, it may not in different kind of environnements.

Hence:

```
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class GameWin implements ActionListener{

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("This is running");
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> new GameWin());
  }
  
  JFrame frame = new JFrame();
  JButton myButton = new JButton("New Window");

  public GameWin(){               
    myButton.setBounds(100,160,200,40);
    myButton.setFocusable(false);
    myButton.addActionListener(this);   
    frame.getContentPane().add(myButton);   
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setSize(420,420);
    frame.setLayout(null);
    frame.setVisible(true);   
  }

  @Override
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    if(e.getSource()==myButton) {
      frame.dispose();          
    }       
  }
}
```

Comment: [Avoid null layouts](https://technojeeves.com/index.php/aliasjava1/114-avoid-null-layouts-in-swing)